# Checking if user input matches any number in the same column

Tags: java, netbeans

Program is 10x10 board, I need to check if the user's input is a duplicate of any number in that same column, but I can't figure it out. When I tried it, it always check the same box. For example, if I entered 4 in [1][1] (going by 10x10 grid), it automatically checks right after I entered that [1][1] is the same as my input and erases it. My professor wants me to check it with the "CheckWinner" method. This is my code so far in my eventhandler:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package firstgui;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;


/**
 *
 * @author douglas moody
 */
 public class EventHandler  implements ActionListener{
     // EventBoard is the name of the array containing all the JButton withi teh EventHandler
     // board (in the other program)  is the name of the array containing all the JButton withi the FirstGui program
     JButton[][] EventBoard;
     private  static String player = " ";
     // this method is called from FirstGui to tell the Eventhandler the board array
     public void setEventBoard (JButton[][] inboard){
        EventBoard = inboard;
     }      

     public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton clickedbutton;

        // clickedbutton will now point to the Button actually clicked
        clickedbutton = (JButton) e.getSource();


        player = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number from 1-10");
        if(player.matches("[1-9]|10")){
            clickedbutton.setText(player);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input", "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        // call the routine to check if the player who just moved won
        if (CheckWinner(player)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,   "Player: " + player + " won");
        }
    }   

    private boolean CheckWinner(String inplayer) {
        int count = 0, count2 = 0;
        // this loop checks the columns on the Board
        for (int i=0; i<=9; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<=9; j++) {
                if (EventBoard[i][j].getText().equals( inplayer )){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "copy");
                    EventBoard[i][j].setText("");
                }
            }
            if (count == 10 && count2 == 10) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the reference the `JButton` that triggered the action to the `CheckWinner` method and simply ignore it when performing you checks...

For example...

```
private boolean CheckWinner(JButton source, String inplayer) {
    //...
    if (EventBoard[i][j] != source && 
            EventBoard[i][j].getText().equals( inplayer )){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "copy");
        EventBoard[i][j].setText("");
    }
```

**Updated...**

To check the values in a given column, you need to know which column to check.  I've not tested this, but something like the example below, should help...

```
private boolean CheckWinner(JButton source, String inplayer) {
    int buttonColumn = -1;
    for (int col = 0; col < EventBoard.length; col++) {
        for (JButton item : EventBoard[col]) {
            if (item == source) {
                buttonColumn = col;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    boolean match = false;
    for (JButton item : EventBoard[buttonColumn]) {
        if (source != item && item.getText().equals(inplayer)) {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

Comment: What do I change "
        for (int i=0; i<=9; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<=9; j++)" to? When I tried entering the same number in a different row and column, it says copy.

Comment: I would imagine you need to figure out which column the original button is in and only use that as the column value for your check

Comment: I tried EventBoard[0][j], to check the first column only, but when I entered same number on the same row, it says copy. Also, when it says copy, it erases the number that was previously entered, not the one that was just entered.

Comment: But what column does the original button reside in?  This is the important part. From your code, it's difficult to know if its `[col][row]` or `[row][col]`...

Comment: I just checked, it's [col][row].